# Highcharts value relative to itself instead of all lines

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way I can have Highchart lines take up all available space?

For example:

I have 2 series. The data of the first serie ranges from 1 to 10. The second serie has a range from 1 to 400. If both series are active I cannot see the difference from the first series as the difference is to small to be displayed.

Comment: Can you show the code which you have tried till now or Fiddle?

Comment: Sadly, most of the information that is entwined in the chart is internal sensitive data which I can't disclose. It would take a long time to take it out so I rather not share what I've got now.

Comment: Have you tried to use two yAxis separated for each serie, like here? http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes

Answer (score 0):

You can change the min and max value of Yaxis dynamically on a click of a button.

This would help the user to see the first series more clearly.

```
 chart.yAxis[0].setExtremes(0,100);
```

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/szy29fs4/

Answer (score 0):

1. You could calculate a relative difference in % for each series, if you want to see the difference and it does not matter to you what the real values are (respectivly you could display them in the mouseover label anyway).
   Thah way you get 2 series from 0 to 100%, so you can see both lines
2. Or simply multiply the small values e.g. by 40. this way you would get a chart from 1 to 400 for both series, and you could nicely see both lines. this is similar to 1. but a little less complicated to achieve